# Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels' doesn't return confusion matrix

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I have a csv file containing estimated probabilities and actual results. I want to create a confusion matrix using a threshold of 0.5 for the estimated probabilities but i keep getting the error message 'Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.' Whats wrong? See code below

I have tried to write the code

## TURN PROBS INTO CLASSES AND DISPLAY FREQUENCIES

```
p_class = ifelse (probs_truth$estimated > 0.5, 1, 0)
table(p_class)
```

## CALCULATING CONFUSION MATRIX

```
predicted = p_class
actual = probs_truth$truth

library(caret)
result = confusionMatrix (data=predicted, reference=actual)
print(result)
```

I expected a confusion matrix table to be returned

Comment: Presumably `data` and `reference` aren't factors with the same levels... hard to say when you don't [provide a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Subsequent code workes for me, hope it helps:
I made a small dataset which I guess resembles your data.

```
library(data.table)
probs_truth <- data.table(estimated = c(0.5, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.1), actual = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0))
```

Added a column to your dataset with the estimated values according to your ifelse statement ('estimated2').

```
probs_truth$estimated2 = ifelse (probs_truth$estimated > 0.5, 1, 0)
```

Made sure 'estimated2' and 'actual' are factors.

```
probs_truth$estimated2 <- as.factor(probs_truth$estimated2)
probs_truth$actual <- as.factor(probs_truth$actual)

head(probs_truth)

library(caret)
result = confusionMatrix (data=probs_truth$estimated2, reference=probs_truth$actual)
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have over 20k values on my csv file. how do i proceed with the csv file? The issue is the code isn't recognizing the file...

Comment: No problem, but we cant really help if you don't provide a sample of your data or at least your code for loading it.